# How to reduce errors in dynamic language such as python, and improve my code quality？

Tags: python

I've always have trouble with dynamic language like Python.

**Several troubles**:

1. Typo error, I can use pylint to reduce some of these errors. But there's still some errors that pylint can not figure out.
2. Object type error, I often forgot what type of the parameter is, int? str? some object? Also, forgot the type of some object in my code.

Unit test might help me sometimes, but I'm not always have enough time to do UT. When I need a script to do a small job, the line of code are 100 - 200 lines, not big, but I don't have time to do the unit test, because I need to use the script as soon as possible. So, many errors appear.

So, any idea on how to reduce the number of these troubles?

Comment: maybe a better fit for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That Python is dynamic makes absolutely no difference here. You don't get more errors or make more mistakes, or even different errors or different mistakes because of that, in my experience. It feels nervous at first because you can't catch errors when you compile, but use pylint or pyflakes for that. But unit testing is the only way to do this, dynamic language or not.

Comment: @LennartRegebro static language will find your object type error in compile time, so it won't be a problem, but in Python, you often forgot what the type it is, and there are no compile time error to tell you this

Comment: No, you just think it will find your object type errors, but what you end up doing is casting types or using void pointers etc, and then the compiler isn't useful anymore. It's false security. You'll get used to not having it with time. It doesn't exist in Python because type errors of that kind does not exist. It's just all objects. The error you get is because you try to make an object do something it can't do. It's not really a type error in the same sense, even when it's called TypeError.

Answer (score 4):

Unit testing *is* the best way to handle this. If you think the testing is taking too much time, ask yourself how much time you are loosing on defects - identifying, diagnosing and rectifying - after you have released the code.

In effect, you are testing in production, and there's plenty of evidence to show that defects found later in the development cycle can be orders of magnitude more expensive to fix.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to unittesting (see chamila_c's answer), sticking to good conventions and coding style helps.  I think I know the sort of one-use scripts you're talking about (assuming that is what you're talking about), and often writing a full test suite for them seems like overkill.  A few other tips which might help:

- Break your code up into functions.  It is often easier to identify a problem, especially a naming problem if you are dealing with a small, isolated piece of code.  It is also much easier to write a unit test for small function.  I find that using this approach means you don't need a full testing suite to test and isolate an identified problem.
- Stick to a consistent, and expressive naming convention.  For example, use `min_value = min(all_values)` rather than something arbitrary like `a = min(b)`.  Same goes for function names, use `def calculate_mean(sequence)` rather than `def f(s)`
- Read and apply [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- Document your code with comments.  This only takes a few seconds while writing the code, and it makes it much easier to figure out what's going on when you come back to it.  Its amazing the detail you can forget just in one day!

Comment: Yeah, I mean one-use scripts, most of time, I am struggling in these scripts, and repair errors. I think you've give some good advices. Thanks!